# Can Google apps for business use php?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

It is my understanding that Google Apps can host websites. If this is true, can it host websites coded in PHP? I just wrote a website for a client in PHP and they want to switch their server to Google apps. Will it work?

Comment: You would need to re-write the app. More info here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_PHP

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is incorrect. [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/intx/en/enterprise/apps/business/) is just a package of Google web applications (GMail, Google Drive, Google Calendar, etc) which you can set up on your domain for a per-user fee.

What you are probably thinking of is [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/app-engine), which is an entirely different product. While it can run some PHP web applications, it is not a standard hosting environment. Your application may require some modification to work under it.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not specify. I am not making an app from PHP, I am wondering if google has web hosting that supports PHP.

Comment: Google App Engine supports PHP, but it is not a web hosting service.

Comment: Still not answering my question, do they have any web hosting service?

Comment: No. Neither Google Apps for Business nor Google App Engine are a general-purpose web hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

you mean the app engine, then yes: https://developers.google.com/appengine/. you should be sure you and the client both know the implications of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented on one the last answer, but I don't have enough rep, yet.

Although it's true that Google App Engine is what you're looking for, signing up for Google Apps is also required if you want to use your own domain with App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your PHP applications in Google AppEngine, recently they announced this feature for public usage https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/ 
There are few limitations, for example you can not write files directly on filesystem.